# OleDbCommandBuilder creates SQL statements that result in "syntax error"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

Can someone please explain why, when I click the "Commit" button, I get the error

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Here's the code.

```
Public Class Form3
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim MaxRows As Integer
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim sql As String

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = D:\TA_Officers.mdb"
        con.Open()
        sql = "SELECT * from TA_OFFICER"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "TA_Officers")
        con.Close()

        MaxRows = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows.Count
        inc = -1
    End Sub

    Private Sub NavigateRecords()
        txtFName.Text = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(1)
        txtMInitial.Text = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(2)
        txtLName.Text = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(3)
        txtContact.Text = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(4)
        txtEmail.Text = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(5)
        txtPosition.Text = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(6)
        txtCourse.Text = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(7)
        txtAddress.Text = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(8)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
        BtnCommit.Enabled = True
        BtnAdd.Enabled = False
        BtnUpdate.Enabled = False
        BtnDel.Enabled = False

        txtPosition.Clear()
        txtLName.Clear()
        txtFName.Clear()
        txtMInitial.Clear()
        txtAddress.Clear()
        txtCourse.Clear()
        txtEmail.Clear()
        txtContact.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RdMember_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RdMember.CheckedChanged
        Label2.Visible = False
        txtPosition.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub RdOfficer_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RdOfficer.CheckedChanged
        Label2.Visible = True
        txtPosition.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFName.Text
        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(2) = txtMInitial.Text
        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(3) = txtLName.Text
        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(4) = txtContact.Text
        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(5) = txtEmail.Text
        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(6) = txtPosition.Text
        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(7) = txtCourse.Text
        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Item(8) = txtAddress.Text

        da.Update(ds, "TA_Officers")

        MsgBox("Data Updated!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnDel.Click
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

        ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows(inc).Delete()
        MaxRows = MaxRows - 1

        inc = 0
        NavigateRecords()
        da.Update(ds, "TA_Officers")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
        BtnCommit.Enabled = False
        BtnAdd.Enabled = True
        BtnUpdate.Enabled = True
        BtnDel.Enabled = True

        inc = 0
        NavigateRecords()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCommit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCommit.Click
        If inc <> -1 Then

            Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

            dsNewRow = ds.Tables("TA_Officers").NewRow()

            dsNewRow.Item("Firstname") = txtFName.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("Middleinitial") = txtMInitial.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("Lastname") = txtLName.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("Mobilenumber") = txtContact.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("Emailaddress") = txtEmail.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("Position") = TxtPosition.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("Course") = txtCourse.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("Address") = txtAddress.Text

            ds.Tables("TA_Officers").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
            **da.Update(ds, "TA_Officers")**

            MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")
            BtnCommit.Enabled = False
            BtnAdd.Enabled = True
            BtnUpdate.Enabled = True
            BtnDel.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnBack.Click
        Form2.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TA_MEMBERSBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TA_MEMBERSBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TA_OfficersDataSet)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

`Position` is a reserved word for JET 4.0 - try to rename the column something else such as `prog_position`. Access will often let you create the column with a reserved name, but when you go to access it in code JET blocks it and gives you a generic `Syntax error in INSERT INTO  Statement` error without being specific. Check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738 for more information on reserved words. It is goods practice to always prefix your column names with something short so that you never run into conflicts or reserved word issues.

Answer (score 2):

As Makita mentions, your problem stems from the fact that `Position` is a reserved word in Jet/ACE SQL. The solution is to add the following two lines of code after you create the `OleDbCommandBuilder` object:

```
cb.QuotePrefix = "["
cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

That will tell the `OleDbCommandBuilder` to generate SQL statements like this

```
INSERT INTO [TA_OFFICER] ([FirstName], ...
```

...instead of

```
INSERT INTO TA_OFFICER (FirstName, ...
```

Wrapping the `Position` column name in those square brackets will tell the Jet database engine that it is a column name, not a keyword.

Comment: I understand the concept here.  But how exactly do you implement the code that you suggest?

Comment: @gromit1 Like I said, you just add the two lines of VB.NET code to set the properties of the `OleDbCommandBuilder` object you created (which in this case was done by `Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)`).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error can happen when you have different data type in the code and in the DB.
Checking the log can give some light on this.