# Load Access from Datatable to Datset to DataGridView and Update Changes in DataGridView to Datatable

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, dataset, oledbdataadapter

I need to load a `DataTable` from Microsoft Access into a `DataSet` using `OleDb`.  I need to load that `DataSet` into a `DataGridView`.  I then need to make changes to the `DataGridView` and update those changes in the original `DataTable` in Microsoft Access.

Here is my code so far:

```
Public tblName As String = "Criteria"

Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim cmdBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder
Dim Bsource As New BindingSource

Public Sub Show_Panel_Manage_Calculations()
    Panel_Manage_Calculations.Show()

    Nordeen_Investing_3.con.Open()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Calculation, [Interval], Formula FROM " & tblName & "", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)
    cmdBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(ds, "Criteria")

    Bsource.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView_Manage_Calculations.DataSource = Bsource
    Nordeen_Investing_3.con.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Update.Click
    Nordeen_Investing_3.con.Open()
    da.Update(ds, "Criteria")
    Nordeen_Investing_3.con.Close()
End Sub
```

Right now my data from the `DataTable` is not being displayed in my `DataGridView`.

Comment: When you create the `OleDbcCommandBuilder` you put square brackets around `Interval`, suggesting that you are aware that it is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access SQL. In that case you might be interested in my recent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19346847/2144390).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataSource` expects a `Table`, not the whole `DataSet`. Also you don't need the `BindingSource` part. Sample code:

```
DataGridView_Manage_Calculations.DataSource = ds.Tables(0) 'By assuming that you want the first table
```

Comment: That worked perfect.  But now I get this error when I try to update: `Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`

Comment: @gromit1 sorry but this has nothing to do with the DataGridView part (not even with the VB.NET part), but with your SQL statement. If it was working before, it has to work now; review the code and make sure that you didn't change any bit.

Comment: @gromit1 Additionally, there is no INSERT INTO in the code you posted?! This error refers to a different part of your application!

Comment: It wasn't working before.  The first step in my problem was to get my `DataTable` to display in the `DataGridView`.  That is now solved thanks to you.  The second step to my problem is the be able to make a change in the `DataGridView` and update the original `DataTable`.

Comment: From my understanding, the `OleDbDataAdapter` should be creating an `INSERT INTO` statement.  But it is not and herein lies my problem.

Comment: @gromit1 OK. But this has nothing to do with INSERT INTO and the code you posted cannot trigger this error...

Comment: @gromit1 I don't have Access to emulate your conditions, but the da.update part should work fine. Alternatively you might do a new call to New OleDbDataAdapter( and write the corresponding SQL statements ("INSERT INTO" or "UPDATE"). Regarding updating the DataGridView you can update the values of the cells directly or by changing the ones in the datasource (ds.Tables(0))

Comment: @gromit1 but I guess that you should do some tests and research for each issue, build your code and come here with specific problems. You wrote everything but the DataGridView wasn't updated because of assigning a wrong DataSource, that's why I answered: specific problems requiring a specific answer (+ generic hints to help you tackle other issues), don't you think?