# How to handle null field when inserting in access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, null, dbnull

I'm trying to Insert values from a form to an Access database but I get an error when the field Value is `Null`. I still get the error even if I use `= DBNull.Value`.

The first 8 value can't be `Null` because those are mandatory fields but once it get to Cost if the field is empty I get this error.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Line 577 is `da.Update(ds, "EquipList")`

This is my code:

```
 Try
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim sql As String
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\equip_full.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=matt"
        con.Open()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM EquipList"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

        da.Fill(ds, "EquipList")
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("EquipList").NewRow()

        ' Equipment Information fields

        dsNewRow.Item(0) = UniqueID
        dsNewRow.Item(1) = InvNumber
        dsNewRow.Item(2) = Item

        dsNewRow.Item(3) = Type

        dsNewRow.Item(4) = Description

        dsNewRow.Item(5) = Manufacturer
        dsNewRow.Item(6) = Model_No
        dsNewRow.Item(7) = Serial_No
        If Cost = "" Then
            dsNewRow.Item(8) = DBNull.Value
        Else
            dsNewRow.Item(8) = Cost
        End If
        If Cost_Centre = "" Then
            dsNewRow.Item(9) = DBNull.Value
        Else
            dsNewRow.Item(9) = Cost_Centre
        End If

        'dsNewRow 10 to 39

        ds.Tables("EquipList").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
        da.Update(ds, "EquipList")
        con.Close()

        MsgBox(Description & " has successfully been added to the system.")

 Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to connect to the database " & ex.ToString)
        Exit Sub
 End Try
```

Update: My code was fine, it was just a problem with the MsgBox. The MsgBox could not show a value that is Null

---

**Removing the MsgBox fixed the problem. It was just there for testing anyway.**

Comment: I just tried to recreate your issue and could not. One thing you could do is try using `.QuotePrefix` and `.QuoteSuffix` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19346847/2144390) and see if that helps.

Comment: Note that the error message is actually complaining about the Prompt parameter to the MsgBox call. Given that contains Description, if Description was null then presumably the Prompt would be null and might throw this error.

Comment: It looks like removing the MsgBox fixed the problem. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should leave it null if you don't set it to anything else.
Have you tried

```
   If Cost > "" Then
        dsNewRow.Item(8) = Cost
    End If
```

?

---

Is the field nullable?
You could also try setting it to zero if it can't be null:

```
   If Cost > "" Then
        dsNewRow.Item(8) = Cost
   Else
        dsNewRow.Item(8) = 0
   End If
```

---

you shouldn't need to explicitly set a date or string value to null, leaving it unset should default the value to null, if it's nullable, which your monetary value may not be.

Your other value, for example, should work with:

```
If Cost_Centre > "" Then
    dsNewRow.Item(9) = Cost_Centre
End If
```

---

this is all assuming your values are nullable, or that they will accept null as a valid value.  Have you confirmed that through the Access interface?

If a string value will not accept null, the default is the empty string, which is the same value as an empty text box.  You should, then, be able to store the value unconditionally just like you're doing with your required values:

```
   If Cost > "" Then
        dsNewRow.Item(8) = Cost
   Else
        dsNewRow.Item(8) = 0
   End If
   dsNewRow.Item(9) = Cost_Centre
```

Comment: Putting 0 fix it for this one but what if the field is a date or a string? I don't think replacing null variable by a space is a smart fix either

Comment: It does not seems to work for Cost_Centre which has the Data Type Text

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Beth's post a bit in case there is a space or something else in the field.

```
 If len(Cost) > 0 Then
    dsNewRow.Item(8) = Cost
End If
```

Comment: If you put a break point at the first line what is the value of "Cost"?

Comment: Sorry it didn't let me finish editing my previous message.   Have you tried is IsNull?  Also if you step though your code, is it hitting "dsNewRow.Item(8) = Cost"  or does the if statement work?  Can you try to have it skip "dsNewRow.Item(8) = Cost".